# Animation not trigger on Diagonal direction unity5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-engine, game-development

[image]

hi there Iam trying learn how to use unity animation system i create function in my code to control animation triggers i only have two walk and attack its work good in 4 normal directions plus i create avatar to mix animation with layers and all works good from my perspective

my problem is when the character face a diagonal direction the attack animation wont trigger as you can see in the gif i attached and whats make me really wonder is when the character face a specific direction which is the up arrow + right arrow the trigger work with this diagonal direction otherwise the attack animation is never work with any other diagonal direction

i tried to create diagonal bool to control this but its not work i tried also to create double transitions on the  animation its also not work

```
public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
Vector3 _CharacterDirection;
Quaternion _CharacterRotation=Quaternion.identity;
Animator _CharacterAnim;
Rigidbody _CharacterRigidbody;
[SerializeField]
public float TurnSpeed;
bool _IsWalking, Isdiagonal;

void Start()
{
    _CharacterAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    _CharacterRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
    CharacterActions();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    CharacterMovement();
}

void CharacterMovement()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    _CharacterDirection.Set(h, 0, v);
    _CharacterDirection.Normalize();

    bool _IsHorizontalChange = !Mathf.Approximately(h, 0f);
    bool _IsVerticalChange = !Mathf.Approximately(v, 0);
    _IsWalking = _IsHorizontalChange || _IsVerticalChange;
    //Isdiagonal = _IsHorizontalChange && _IsVerticalChange ? true : false;
    _CharacterAnim.SetBool("IsWalking", _IsWalking);

     Vector3 _DesairdForward = Vector3.RotateTowards(this.transform.forward, _CharacterDirection, TurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    _CharacterRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_DesairdForward);


    _CharacterRigidbody.MovePosition(_CharacterRigidbody.position + _CharacterDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    _CharacterRigidbody.MoveRotation(_CharacterRotation);

}

void CharacterActions()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        _CharacterAnim.SetTrigger("SpellCast");
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _IsWalking)
    {
        _CharacterAnim.SetTrigger("SpellCast");

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code (just that `else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _IsWalking)` will never be true). The problem probably is somewhere in your animation transitions.

Comment: hmmm its work in one diagonal direction do you think every diagonal need his separate animation like blend tree with multi walk directions ?